# Ubuntu hard blocked my wireless

Tags: wireless, networking

Originally I had Windows 8 and decided to dual boot with Ubuntu. I really liked Ubuntu, so I removed Windows 8 and am now only running Ubuntu. The wireless was working fine until I rebooted my computer, but now it won't recognize any Wi-Fi access points.

When I typed `rfkill list all`, everything is unblocked except `phy0`, which is hard blocked. I tried `rfkill unblock all` but that didn't work. I've also tried a few other terminal commands, but nothing seems to work.

It works if I have my laptop plugged into the internet with a wired connection (which is what I'm using now).

What should I do?

Comment: If it did work(!) then "hard blocked" probably exactly means what it says: it is -hardware- that is blocking wifi so think bios, that switch on the side of your notebook or the keycombo Fn+functionkey (you need the one with the wireless icon) or a dedicated wifi button on your keyboard. Now... which one it is depends on your hardware ;)

Comment: On my system (dual-boot), if I disable wireless on Windows and shut down, Ubuntu is not able to unblock it. Since I rarely use Windows, I simply make sure to leave Wifi enabled before I shut down. Unfortunately, since you removed Windows I don't have any suggestion.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the entire output of: rfkill list all